# How to get row index of selected row in PrimeFaces data table using jsf 2.2

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

for example I am using this datatable

```
<h:form>
        <p:dataTable var="item" value="#{kilowatManager.show}">
            <p:column headerText="Id">
                <h:outputText value="#{kilowatManager.kilowat.id}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Name">
                <h:outputText value="#{kilowatManager.kilowat.name}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="kWH">
                <h:outputText value="#{kilowatManager.kilowat.kwh}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="kWD">
                <p:inputText value="#{kilowatManager.kilowat.kwd}"/>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
```

How can I get values of selected row after pressing ENTER key in input text

Answer (score 0):

you can use a button after selecting your row. you can place your button inside datable. for example you can include it inside `f:facet` tag

```
<f:facet name="footer">
<p:commandButton id="createButton" icon="ui-icon-plus"   value="Nouveau"/>
<p:commandButton id="editButton"   icon="ui-icon-pencil" type="submit" value="Modifier"  action="#{Controller.Method()}">
```

you tie your button to a backing bean like this:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "controller")
@RequestScoped
public class Controller implements Serializable {

    public Controller() {
    }

    public void method(){

        DataTable dataTable = (DataTable) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent("form:datalist");
        MyDataTableObject myObject = (MyDataTableObject) dataTable.getSelection();            
    } 
}
```

Where *form* and *datalist* is the id of the `h:form` and `p:dataTable` tag

i was stuck in this problem and i found my solution using the following link
http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=29086